# Running variable threads in C# application based on Processor type

Tags: c#, windows, multithreading, processor

I am writing a Windows Application in C# that will essentially be a multi-threaded one. But I am in a fix because this application can be run on a Celeron/P-IV system to a Core i7 system. So, I am unable to decide how to determine the number of threads to spawn for this application.

Is there any way to determining how many threads I can spawn depending on the processor used to leverage the maximum power of the CPU as well as make my application not lag/slow down/freeze? Is there any kind of general formula that you use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'd consider using the `ThreadPool`. As far as I know, the .NET framework manages the optimum number of threads itself (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

`Environment.ProcessorCount` is what you're looking for.

For the second part of your question, the best way to do that is with testing a different number of threads.  It all depends on what exactly your threads are doing, do they spend a large time blockig, or they may be sharing common system resources, hitting each others cache lines, whatever, so you can't really give a general formula for this sort of thing.  It's all heavily dependent on your specific thread behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of logical processors you can use `System.Environment.ProcessorCount`, however it will be different from actual processors/cores count on a HyperThreading enabled systems. To get more accurate information you will need to use WMI metadata `Win32_ComputerSystem.NumberOfProcessors` and `Win32_ComputerSystem.NumberOfLogicalProcessors`.

However I would recommend to let the system take care of scheduling and use one of the high level multithreading subsystems like [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.aspx) or [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx)